# To get value of the link using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value of linl which is generated from db using while loop.
When I prees on the link it should show alert window with its name.

```
while($trackResultRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackResult)){?>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="rem" 
       data-userid="<?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?>" 
       data-track="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_path']?>">
        <span><?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?></span> -
        <span><?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?></span>
      </a>
      <hr/>
    </li>

<hr>
<?php
}
?>
```

And Jquery code

```
 $(function() {
 $(".rem").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $link = $(this), // save for later
  username = $(this).data("userid"),
  track = $(this).data("track");
  return alert (username);

  });
});
```

But it does not work....Can anybody help me to fix this code?

Comment: You script is on the bottom of `body`? Before `</body>` closing tag?

Comment: Add `console.log( $(this).data() );` to your click event to see what, if anything, is being read by the data function.

Answer (score 0):

You code is working for me, however I noticed that your two anchor tags are very close to each other. Are you adding event listener to first anchor tag and clicking on second? See example code below

```js
$(function() {
  $(".rem").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this), // save for later
      username = $link.data("userid"),
      track = $link.data("track");
    return alert(username);

  });
});
```

```css
.glyphicon:after {
  content: 'Icon'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="rem" data-userid="USERNAME" data-track="TRACK_NAME">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right "></span>
    </a>
    <a href="track_path">
      <span>username</span> -
      <span>track_name</span>
    </a>
    <hr/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="rem" data-userid="USERNAME" data-track="TRACK_NAME">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right "></span>
    </a> -
    <a href="track_path">
      <span>username</span> -
      <span>track_name</span>
    </a>
    <hr/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The first 'li' is without space and second with space between anchor tags